# Waiting for JavaScript to execute to continue Java code

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, pagination

I have a reader application that uses a web view to display html files with pagination, I am having hard time calculating the pageCount of the number of pages right after the web view finishes load. What I have so far in the function onPageFinished I have the following code:

```
myWebView.loadUrl("javascript:window.HTMLOUT.calculatePageCount(document.getElementsByTagName('html')[0].scrollWidth);");
            if(myWebView.getDonePageCalc())
            {
                 //do some calculation    
            }
```

In my web view Class I have implemented calculatePageCount and inside it I set donePageCalc to true. What I need is for the code to wait until the web view has finished executing the JavaScript instruction to calculate the page count. if I do it this way:

```
 while(!myWebView.getDonePageCalc())
 {System.out.println("wait");}
```

The program will freeze inside the while loop.

In there way to set an observer or anything that could trigger the fact the execution of the instruction is done?

Answer (score 0):

If you know excat time for waiting, you can use,

```
try {
    Thread.sleep(1000); // In millisecond                
} catch(InterruptedException ex) {
    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();
}
```

Or else you can try,

```
while(true){
   if(myWebView.getDonePageCalc()){
       //do your calculation
       break;
   }
}
```

Comment: ّI don't know the exact time but I will try it though.

Comment: I'm afraid both suggestion didn't work, in the first case it waited for the set time but the pages were not calculated, in the second suggestion the program stays eternally in the while loop.